# Calculate multiple result from inputs and replace in label KIVY

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

An app for getting width, length, and price and calculating results

In this I have 3 entries and one button that will click on that information to be calculated instead of labels

E.g :
1 --> Input1 , Input2 , Input3 all is in float 
2 --> Press Button to Calculate i have multiple answers and multiple labels
**How can set result in labels** ?

[App ui in graphical test (real verison in debug mode on andriod)][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/byNwG.jpg

Main.py

```
    import kivy
    kivy.require('1.0.7')
    
    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
    from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
    from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
    
    class root(BoxLayout):
    
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super(root, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    
    
        def cal(self):
            print(int(self.ertefa.input_text))
            pass
    
    class HeroApp(App):
        kv_directory = 'template1'
    
        def build(self):
            return root()
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        HeroApp().run()



<hr>
kv File:

    #:kivy 1.0
    <root>:
        BoxLayout:
            orientation:'vertical'
    
            Image:
                source:'top.png'
                allow_stretch: True
                size_hint: 1 , None
        # -------------------------------------------
            GridLayout:
                id:'inputs"
                rows:3
                col:2
                size_hint: 1, .4
                padding : 5
    
    
        # INPUT ---[ ERTEFA ASLI ]---------------------------
    
                TextInput:
                    id: ertefaa
                    input_filter : 'float'
                    multiline: False
                    font_size: 42
                    text: ''
    
                Image:
                    source:'img1.png'
    
        # INPUT ---[ ARZ ASLI ]------------------------------
    
                TextInput:
                    id: arzz
                    input_filter : 'float'
                Image:
                    source:'img2.png'
    
        # INPUT ---[ GHEYMAT ]--------------------------------
    
                TextInput:
                    id: gheymatt
                    input_filter : 'float'
                Image:
                    source:'img3.png'
    
        # PROC --[ Def Button ]------------------------------
    
            Button:
                size_hint: 1, .15
                text: 'TURSAN CALLCULATE'
                on_press : ertefaa - 6
    
    
        # ----------------------------------------------------
            GridLayout:
                id: 'outputs'
                rows:9
                col:2
                padding : 5
    
    
        # OUTPUT ---[ ERTEFA FRAME ]--------------------------
    
                Label:
                    id : ertefaframe
                    text: '213'
                    color:[10,1,255,1]
                    font_size : 26
                Image:
                    source:'out1.png'
    
    
        # OUTPUT ---[ ARZ FRAME ]--------------------------
    
                Label:
                    id : arzframe
                    text: '213'
                    font_size : 26
                Image:
                    source:'out2.png'
    
    
        # OUTPUT ---[ MOTAHAREK ]--------------------------
                Label:
                    id : motaharek
                    text: '213'
                    font_size : 26
                Image:
                    source:'out3.png'
    
    
        # OUTPUT ---[ ERTEFA TUR ]------------------------
                Label:
                    id : erteftur
                    text: '213'
                    font_size : 26
                Image:
                    source:'out4.png'
    
    
        # OUTPUT ---[ GAM TUR ]---------------------------
    
                Label:
                    id : gamtur
                    text: '213'
                    font_size : 26
                Image:
                    source:'out5.png'
    
        # OUTPUT ---[ METRE MORABA ]------------------------
                Label:
                    id : metr
                    text: '213'
                    font_size : 26
                Image:
                    source:'out6.png'
    
        # OUTPUT ---[ GHEYMAT KOLL ]------------------------
                Label:
                    id: gheymatkoll
                    text: '213'
                    font_size : 26
                Image:
                    source:'out7.png'
    
        # INFO ---[ ADDRESS ]------------------------
            Image:
                source:'down.png'
                size_hint: 1, None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From kivy [documentation](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.label.html#kivy.uix.label.Label.text):

> **text**
>
> Text of the label.
>
> Creation of a simple hello world:
>
> `widget = Label(text='Hello world')`
>
> If you want to create the widget with an unicode string, use:
>
> `widget = Label(text=u'My unicode string')`
>
> text is a *StringProperty* and defaults to ‘’.

If you want to change the text of a specific label, simply retrieve by using its id, and then set the desired text:

```
self.ids.id_of_label_you_want_to_change.text = "Text you want to set"
```

Comment: I find other wy to solve 
`
 Button :

                text: 'Mohasebe'
                on_press : root.product(*args)
`
`
class root(BoxLayout):
    # -- For define
    def product(self, instance):
     pass
`